# Call Objects all at once into Function returning a specific calculation with each of them?

Tags: javascript, function, object

How can I call each object of `var auto` without a explicit way?

I mean without having to write each of them in the function-call, in the `speedAverage` function and the `return` for calculating the average.

```
function Car (model, speed) {
    this.model = model;
    this.speed = speed;
}


var speedAverage = function(car1, car2, car3) {
    return (car1.speed + car2.speed + car3.speed)/ veh.length;
};



var auto = [
new Car("BMW", 220),
new Car("Ford", 260),
new Car("DeLorean", 350)
];

console.log("The average between these cars is " + speedAverage(auto[0], auto[1], 
auto[2]));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very easily with the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method. This function is used to call a function with the contents of an array as the parameters:

```
speedAverage.apply(null, auto);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pass the array object to the function:

```
var speedAverage = function (arr) {
  var sum=0
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
     sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum/arr.length;
}
```

and  call it with speedAverage (auto)

you can also read about arguments if you are looking for functions with variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Add a static function to `Car` and push the speed in the constructor, then you don’t have to do the `auto` thing:

```
var speeds = [];
function Car (model, speed) {
    this.model = model;
    this.speed = speed;
    speeds.push(speed);
}

Car.getAverageSpeed = function() {
  return eval(speeds.join('+'))/speeds.length;
};

new Car("BMW", 220),
new Car("Ford", 260),
new Car("DeLorean", 350)

console.log("The average between these cars is " + Car.getAverageSpeed());
```

Or you can use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) and [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like this:

```
var speedAverage = function() {
    return eval(Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function(s) {
        return s.speed;
    }).join('+'))/arguments.length;
};

var auto = [
    new Car("BMW", 220),
    new Car("Ford", 260),
    new Car("DeLorean", 350)
];

console.log("The average between these cars is " + speedAverage.apply(0, auto));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have all your data in the `auto` array use the reduce function :

```
console.log (auto.reduce (
   function (speed, car) { 
     return speed + car.speed; 
   }, 0) / auto.length);
```

The call to `reduce` returns the sum of the speeds of all the cars in `auto`, divide that divided by the number of cars gives you the average.